# Uninstall SUMO 0.22

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-14.04, ubuntu-12.04, sumo

I need to remove [SUMO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simulation_of_Urban_MObility) 0.22 in order to install SUMO 0.25. I have been using Ubuntu since 2009, but I never came across this problem.

I tried:

```
sudo apt-get remove sumo
sudo apt-get remove --auto-remove sumo
sudo apt-get purge sumo
sudo apt-get purge --auto-remove sumo
```

*None* of the above is working. The output is shown:

[image]

I went to *usr/local/bin/* and found both *sumo* and *sumo-gui* there + some other important executables needed for *sumo*. I installed SUMO by downloading the .tar file and used *./configure*, *make*, and *make install*.

I need to work on veins which no longer supports SUMO 0.22.

Comment: Please review *[Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/)* (e.g., *"Images should only be used to illustrate problems that* ***can't be made clear in any other way***, *such as to provide screenshots of a user interface.*) and take the appropriate [action](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/36256049/edit) (it covers answers as well). Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you installed using `make install` you cannot hope for `apt-get remove` to work. apt-get can only uninstall packages it installed. If you still have the directory where you did the `./configure & make` and `sudo make install` then go there and do `sudo make uninstall`. If not:

```
cd /usr/local/bin
sudo rm activitygen dfrouter emissionsDrivingCycle jtrrouter marouter od2trips sumo-gui TraCITestClient duarouter emissionsMap netconvert netgenerate polyconvert sumo
```

This should remove all binaries. I did not check whether all of them were already present in 0.22 so if it is complaining about missing files leave them out.

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded SUMO 0.25 and did it the same way. I installed SUMO 0.22, unzipped the download folder, and went to the SUMO 0.25 directory,

```
./configure
 make
 make install
```

without removing the previous 0.22 version. I tested it worked. It worked with Python, TrAci 4J and Omnet++. I have not tried netconvert or josm yet, but I believe it would work too.